# Como calcular a media de uma coluna no RStudio mas ignorar os valores 0 da coluna?

Tags: r

exemplo coluna 1 = 1 2 3 4 0 0 0 a media normal disso daria 1.428571
porem ignorando os 0 seria 2.5, gostaria de saber como fazer isso, ignorando os valores 0 da coluna.

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que o conjunto de dados se chama `dados` e tenha duas colunas chamadas `c1` e `c2`, com os seguintes valores:

```
dados <- data.frame(c1=c(1:4, rep(0, 3)), c2=7:1)
dados
  c1 c2
1  1  7
2  2  6
3  3  5
4  4  4
5  0  3
6  0  2
7  0  1
```

faça o seguinte:

```
mean(dados[dados$c1!=0, 1])
```

O código acima seleciona as linhas de `dados` cujos valores da primeira coluna sejam diferentes de 0. Além disso, considera apenas a primeira coluna do data frame. Com as linhas e coluna corretas selecionadas, basta calcular o valor da média.

Uma maneira alternativa de chamar a primeira coluna é, em vez de colocar o número 1, chamá-la pelo nome, como o comando abaixo faz:

```
dados[dados$c1!=0, "c1"]
```

O resultado será o mesmo, independente do método utilizado.

Comment: Isso, exatamente o que eu necessitava ! obrigado !!

Comment: Então, se possível, aceite minha resposta, [como explicado aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).

Answer (score 0):

Uma resposta alternativa à proposta pelo Marcus Nunes seria utilizar o exemplo abaixo. Tomei a liberdade de usar o conjunto de dados proposto por ele. Farei uso neste exemplo dos pacotes abaixo. Certifique-se de tê-los em seu computador.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
dados <- data.frame(c1=c(1:4, rep(0, 3)), c2=7:1)
dados
```

Supondo que você deseja a média da coluna c1, você pode usar a função `filter` do dplyr para filtrar os dados diferentes de zero da coluna c1. Cria-se um objeto com o resultado desta operação, para, em seguida, usar a função `summarise` do mesmo pacote para gerar uma coluna chamada MEDIA com a média dos dados filtrados. A solução é apresentada de duas maneiras, com ou sem o *pipe* do pacote magrittr.

Sem o *pipe* do pacote magritrr

```
dt.filtro <- filter(dados, c1 != 0)
summarise(dt.filtro, MEDIA = mean(c1))
```

Com o *pipe* do magrittr, você pode evitar a criação de objetos como o 'dt.filtro' do exemplo acima.

```
dados %>% filter(c1 != 0) %>% summarise(MEDIA = mean(c1))
```

Caso você queira ver as médias das duas colunas, baseadas na exclusão de valores da coluna c1, por exemplo, basta você utilizar uma variante de `summarise` chamada `summarise_each`.

```
dados %>% filter(c1 != 0) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))
```